# help with translation! what's ようわからんなんて?

Tags: grammar, translation, dialects

In a manga I found this line:

> よう わからんなんて、こっちの台詞だ。

What's that よう at the beginning? Is different from "you ni"?

And わからんなんて?

Since the character is confused about a phrase another one said, he's talking about it with another, but I'm not sure about the meaning.

Is it correct: "I don't understand his speech."
I'm confused...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is basically, but certainly not exclusively, Western-Japan speech.

「よう」 = 「よく」 = "well" or "very well" in this context.  It can also mean "often".

This has ***nothing*** to do with 「ように」 or 「ような」, which means "like ~~", "as ~~", etc.

「わからん」 = 「わからない」 = "I don't get it.", "I don't understand.", etc.

「～～なんて」 = "stuff/thing/something like ~~".  Think of it as an informal quotative particle.  It has nothing to do with the exclamatory 「[何]{なん}て」.

> ようわからんなんて、こっちの[台詞]{せりふ}だ。

If it helped one understand this sentence better, one could alter it to:

> 『ようわからん』なんて、こっちの台詞だ。
>
> = "(He said) "I don't really get it.", but those are my words!"